# compute double integral$ \iint_{r\leq |x-y|\leq 2r}{\rm d}x{\rm d}y$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to compute the following double intergal but I do not know how to do
$$
\iint_{r\leq |x-y|\leq 2r}{\rm d}x{\rm d}y
$$
where $(x,y)\in \mathbb R^3 \times \mathbb R^3$ and $r$ is a positive constant.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to see your specific region is a diagonal strip parallel to $y=x$ which has width $2r$, since
$$
|x-y| \le r \iff |y-x| \le r \iff -r \le y-x \le r \iff x-r \le y \le x+r.
$$
Since this strip has finite width and infinite length, the double integral (which is the area of the strip) diverges.

However, if you are trying to integrate some function $f(x,y)$, you would need to parameterize the interval, and one way to do that is to use the last inequality, taking $x$ over the entire real range, to get
$$
\int_{x=-\infty}^{x=\infty} \int_{y=x-r}^{y=x+r} f(x,y)\ dy\ dx.
$$

---

**UPDATE**

Consider as you are suggesing $f(x,y) = 1$ and $r = 1/n$, then
$$
\int_{x=-\infty}^{x=\infty} \int_{y=x-1/n}^{y=x+1/n} dy\ dx
 = \int_{x=-\infty}^{x=\infty} \frac{2}{n}\ dx
$$
so if you want to define the dependency between $n$ and $x$ somehow, that would help. Naively, as $n \to \infty$, the diagonal strip becomes a line, and hence will have $0$ area. More formally, you need
$$
\lim_{N \to \infty} \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{-N}^N \frac{2}{n}\ dx
 = \lim_{N \to \infty} \int_{-N}^N \left( \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2}{n}\right)dx
 = \lim_{N \to \infty} \int_{-N}^N 0 dx
 = 0.
$$

Note, however, that the relationship between $N$ and $n$ there becomes important. In other words, assuming it is the same limit, so letting $N=n$, you get
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{-n}^n \frac{2}{n}\ dx
= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2}{n} \int_{-n}^n dx
= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2}{n} (2n)
= 4.
$$

Comment: thank you gt6989b. In fact I want to prove that if $u$ is a function in $H^{1}(\mathbb R^3 \times \mathbb R^3)$ then $n\mathbb{1}(|x-y|\leq 1/n)\nabla u \to 0$ in $L^2(\mathbb R^3 \times \mathbb R^3)$ when $n\to \infty$. I tried to use Holder's inequality and Sobolev's inequality, but then it required to compute the above integration. Do you have any idea to prove this?.

Comment: @Muniain see if the update helps

Comment: thank you. What happen if I change the domain of the integration from $|x-y| \leq 2r$ to $r\leq |x-y| \leq 2r$?.

Comment: @Muniain think geometrically what that would do to your region. You should end up with 2 parallel strips...